# How to pass an object of anonymous functions to another object?

Tags: roku, brightscript, scenegraph

I am trying to create a bunch of callback functions that are in an Associative Array, which then is saved to another Scenegraph object's interface field.

However, when accessing the interface field in the same object, it states that the function is invalid.

Object 1:

```
callbacks = {
    afterchildcreatecallback: function ()
      print "THIS IS A CALLBACK FUNCTION"
      return 1
    end function
  }

  m.contentReader = createObject("roSGNode", "ContentReader")
  m.contentReader.observeField("content", "setLists")
  m.contentReader.contenturi = "pkg:/data/contentLists/" + settingFocused.id + "Data.xml"
  m.contentReader.callbacks = callbacks
  m.contentReader.control = "RUN"
```

Object 2:

```
<component name = "ContentReader" extends = "Task" >
  <script type = "text/brightscript" uri="pkg:/components/taskRunners/contentReader.brs"></script>

  <interface>
    <field id = "contenturi" type = "uri"></field>
    <field id = "content" type = "node"></field>
    <field id = "callbacks" type = "assocarray"></field>
  </interface>

</component>
```

When accessing the callbacks field in Object 2, I can see the added object but the function that was defined inside it, is invalid.

Is this allowed? Or do I have to pass the function through a `setter` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't store functions in a interface associative array field. That's either a BrightScript limitation or a design feature.
If you want to use a listener-callback pattern, you can still do so using interface functions through `callFunc()`.

YourNode.xml

```
<component name="YourNode" extends="Node">
  <interface>
    <function name="myCallback"/>
  </interface>
</component>
```

YourNode.brs

```
sub init()
  m.contentReader = createObject("roSGNode", "ContentReader")
  m.contentReader.listener = m.top
  (...)
end sub

sub myCallback(params)
  ?"params "params
end sub
```

ContentReader.xml

```
<component name="ContentReader" extends="Task">
  <interface>
    (...)
    <field id="listener" type="node"/>
  </interface>
</component>
```

ContentReader.brs

```
sub onTaskDone()
  params = ...
  m.top.listener.callFunc("myCallback", params)
end sub
```

Also, make sure to "release" the listener reference after you're done with it, you can do that from `YourNode` by doing `m.contentReader.listener = invalid`. This would avoid memory leaks caused by circular references.